# Update field through link_to in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a tree of products in Rails 3.2 and would like to have an add/remove feature so that users can add new children products or remove existing children for a product. I use the ancestry gem to generate the tree, for a Product 1 it might look like this:

```
Product 1
add | remove
    Product 2
    add | remove
        Product 3
        add | remove
```

In a partial _product.html.erb I have added Add and Remove links, which works for the add feature, but I cannot get the remove link to work:

```
<span><%= product.name.capitalize %></span>
<%= link_to "Add", new_product_path(parent_id: product) %> | 
<%= link_to "Remove", {parent_id: nil}, method: :update %>
```

I would like to update the parent_id to nil for the product to be removed when "Remove" is clicked, but the above link_to doesn't seem to be working. I get an: *No route matches [POST] "/products/1/edit"* routing error. In my product_controller I have:

```
def update
   if @product.update_attributes(params[:product])
     flash[:success] = "Product updated"
     redirect_to @product
   else
     render 'edit'
  end
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**

I tried to use `method: put` instead:

```
<%= link_to "Remove", {parent_id: nil}, method: :put %>
```

then I get a `No route matches [PUT] "/products/1/edit"` error instead when clicking on the link.

I can now change/remove the parent using a form, not at all what I want but anyway:

```
<%= form_for @product do |f| %>    
    <%= f.label :parent_id %>
    <%= f.text_field :parent_id %>
    <%= f.submit "Update", class: "btn" %>  
<% end %>
```

Would it be possible to automatically pass the parent_id: nil into the form so that when you hit Update, it sets the parent_id: nil (not having a text field just a button)?

Comment: What does your `config/routes.rb` contain for products?

Comment: My routes.rb have this for the products: resources :products, only: [:edit, :update, :show, :index, :create, :destroy, :new]

Comment: you could `<%= f.hidden_field :parent_id, nil %>` (btw you can still have the link if you want to - you have to explicitly point it to the url for update (/products/1 in your case) - `rake routes` is your friend)

Comment: @froderik: I have tried `:parent_id, nil`, but then I get an `undefined method `merge' for nil:NilClass`error? I have also tried using hidden_field_tag :parent_id, nil, which doesn't throw an error but the field is not updated...

Comment: if you use hidden_field_tag you'll have to pick up :parent_id 'by hand' in your controller: `@product.parent_id = params[:parent_id]`

Comment: @froderik: Thanks, that is very useful to know. I will try picking it up in the controller.

Comment: @froderik: works as well, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
<%= link_to "Remove", update_products_path(product:{parent_id: nil}), method: :put %>
```

There is no HTTP-Verb `update` what you need is `put`. You can read about Rails and HTTP-Verbs 
[here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: Tried with put, get an error: `No route matches [PUT] "/products/1/edit"`

Comment: thats because your code points to `edit` which wont respond to `put`

Comment: i guess that is because I do this under the edit page for the product, should it point to the product instead?

Comment: Think of it this way: `new` uses GET to present an empty form that you use to `create` and object using POST; `edit` uses GET to present a form filled with the current state of data so that you use to `update` the object using PUT.  `new` and `edit` display data, `create` and `update` save it.  Displaying always uses the HTTP GET verb, create uses POST and update uses PUT.

Comment: @TomHarrisonJr: Thanks! That makes it more clear. I could use a form for updating the parent_id, I tried this for other parameters such as name of product and so on, and it seems to work. However, a link to change the parent_id is more neat.

Comment: How would the helper function above, update_products_path, look like that takes the argument `product:{parent_id: nil}`, and where the path is `/products/id`? I tried to write one, but without success.

Answer (score 2):

I finally got it to work thanks to @krichard answer together with @froderiks comment, by setting the path to /products/id and passing `parent_id: nil` using `method: :put`:

```
<%= link_to "Remove", "/products/#{product.id}?product%5Bparent_id%5D=", method: :put %>
```

The same effect can be achieved using form_for and a hidden_field ([Passing a fixed value to a field using a button/link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13690829/passing-a-fixed-value-to-a-field-using-a-button-link)):

```
<%= form_for product do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :parent_id, value: nil %>
  <%= f.submit "Remove", class: "btn" %>
<% end %>
```

If a hidden_field_tag is used instead of f.hidden_field, :parent_id must be picked up in the controller (thanks @froderik):

```
<%= form_for product do |f| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :parent_id, nil %>
  <%= f.submit "Remove", class: "btn" %>
<% end %>
```

**products_controller.rb**

```
def update
  @product.parent_id = params[:parent_id]
  ...
end
```