# Passing a fixed value to a field using a button/link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How can I set a field of an object to a fixed value using a button or link in Rails? It seems like this should be a fairly basic procedure, but I haven't been successful with it. An example would be to set the parent_id of a product model to nil (related earlier question [Update field through link_to in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13687085/update-field-through-link-to-in-rails)). I have managed to achieve this through a form by leaving the text field empty:

```
<%= form_for @product do |f| %>    
    <%= f.label :parent_id %>
    <%= f.text_field :parent_id %>
    <%= f.submit "Update", class: "btn" %>  
<% end %>
```

But how can this be done without a text field, simply using a button, so that the parent_id is set to nil when the button is pressed? I have also tried to set the parent_id in a hidden field, but that doesn't work.

```
<%= form_for @product do |f| %>
   <%= f.hidden_field parent_id: nil %>
   <%= f.submit "Remove", class: "btn" %>
<% end %>
```

The controller looks like this for the edit/update actions.

**products_controller.rb**

```
def edit
   @product = Product.find_by_id(params[:id])    
end

def update
  if @product.update_attributes(params[:product])
    flash[:success] = "Product updated"
    redirect_to @product
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

**Edit**

See [Update field through link_to in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13687085/update-field-through-link-to-in-rails) for how to do this using link_to instead of a form.

Comment: please show your controller code and maybe model code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<%= f.hidden_field :parent_id, value: nil %>
```

instead of

```
<%= f.hidden_field parent_id: nil %>
```

And make sure `parent_id` is in `attr_accessible` list of the model.

Comment: Thanks, but I get an error `undefined method `merge' for nil:NilClass`, using :parent_id, nil...?

Comment: If you are using the form helper version then you should not pass a second parameter. Either of the following should work: `f.hidden_field :parent_id` or `hidden_field_tag :parent_id, nil`.

Comment: @AndrewHubbs: Thanks. With `f.hidden_field :parent_id` I cannot  update the value of parent_id to nil? I don't get an error with `hidden_field_tag :parent_id, nil`, but it doesn't seem to update the value of the field (also tried other fields than parent_id, e.g. :name which doesn't work either)?

Comment: graphmeter, try `<%= f.hidden_field :parent_id, value: nil %>`

Comment: @alex: Thanks a lot! Works great with value: nil.

Comment: If a `hidden_field_tag :parent_id, nil` is used the `parent_id` has to be picked up in the controller: `@product.parent_id = params[:parent_id]`.